# Noether's theorem in Altland/Simmons "Condensed Matter Field Theory"

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, noethers-theorem

I'm reading Sec. 1.6 of "Condensed Matter Field Theory", 3e, by Altland and Simmons, where the authors derive Noether's theorem. They consider the following mapping of the spacetime coordinates:

$$
x^\mu\rightarrow x'^\mu = x^\mu + \partial_{\omega_a}x^\mu\vert_{\omega=0} \,\omega_a(x)\tag{$\ast$}
$$

where "for a three-dimension rotation, $\omega$ would be the rotation angles, etc.". I understand the derivation of the Noether currents which follows this. But this mapping confuses me: aren't $x^\mu$ the independent variables? How can they differentiated with respect to $\omega$?

If somebody could show how a simple translation or rotation of the coordinates can be recast in the form of Eq. $(\ast)$, that would be very helpful to me.

Thank you!

Comment: That statement is simply the Taylor expansion to first order. For the Noether theorem, you need to consider a "variation" which exactly corresponds to this.

Comment: @Fabian Could you elaborate? What function am I Taylor expanding? Does $x^\mu$ depend parametrically on $\omega$?

Comment: The variation is parameterized by $\omega$ (for each variation you have an $\omega_a$). As a result, we have $x'{}^\mu$ a function of $\omega_a$ with $x'{}^\mu (\omega = 0) =x^\mu$.

Comment: Think about translation (in the $\mu=1$ direction). If $\omega$ generates translation, we have $x'{}^\mu = x^\mu + \omega \, \delta^\mu_{1}$. In this case, there is no linearization needed and we simply have $\partial_{\omega} x^\mu |_{\omega =0}= \delta^{\mu}_1$.

Comment: @Fabian So the transformation is $x^\mu\rightarrow x^\mu(\omega(x))$, which gives the result from Altland/Simmons after Taylor-expanding in $\omega$? Does the fact that $\omega$ is itself a function of the old coordinates $x^\mu$ mean that every point $x^\mu$ is transformed differently, like in an elastic deformation?

Comment: Yes, it is like an elastic transformation. In general, the transformation might heavily deform the system and still be a symmetry.